# How to maintain isactive flag with following query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in that i have data like column name datatype table name, status and isactive flag.

I have to read data from this table and create a query which will work according to information given in table.

Like column name is given table name is given and if status is new then i have to create a new table and with column name and data type given in my data table.
If status is old then i have to run alter command and add a column with name and datatype given.
But my problem is how should i maintain the flag in my data table so after executing in rows it will execute in next rows only not again in all rows otherwise it will give error that table name already exist if we will create again.
And how should i also create primary key if column has yes in data table.

Data table:

| column | datatype | tablename | status | prmarykey | isactive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | varchar(10) | emp | new | no | 1 |
| id | int | emp | new | yes | 1 |
| email | varchar(250) | details | old | no | 1 |

I have the following solution so far from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65665036/2029983):

```
 DECLARE @temp nvarchar(max) = 
(SELECT STRING_AGG(query, ' ')
FROM (
    SELECT
        query = 'CREATE TABLE ' + 
            QUOTENAME(table_name) +
            ' ( ' +
            STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(cl) + ' ' + data_type , ', ') +
            ' );'

    FROM dataset
    WHERE status = 'new' 
    GROUP BY table_name
) AS v); 

SET @temp = @temp + 
(SELECT STRING_AGG(query,' ')
FROM (
    SELECT
        query = 'ALTER TABLE ' + 
            QUOTENAME(table_name) +
            ' ADD ' +
            
            STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(cl) + ' ' + data_type  ,  ', ') 
            
    FROM dataset
    WHERE status = 'old' 
    GROUP BY table_name
) AS v);

print(@sql)
EXEC(@temp)
```

This is solution but in this how should i make changes so it will update flag to 0 after execution and also add column as primary key if our data table has yes in primary key.

This is @temp after succesful execution:

```
CREATE TABLE [emp] ( [name] varchar(10), [id] int ); ALTER TABLE [details ] ADD [email] varchar(250)
```

Thanks in advance..!!!!!

Comment: please do a `print @temp` before you `exec(@temp)` and edit your question to include that

Comment: it help us understand your dynamic query.

Comment: Done, now please help to implement required two logics

Comment: I mean for you to execute it and then show us the output of `print @temp`.

Comment: now added sir this will be the @temp statement , i just want to add primary key in create table and in alter also if column is primary keynd update the flag to 0 after execution of all rows with same target table name

Comment: Thanks for the (non)attribution of my answer to your other question

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a `isexist` column and then `JOIN` to `sys.columns` to update it after you have execute your `create table` or `alter table` query

```
update  t
set     isexist = 1
from    data_table t
        inner join sys.columns c    on  c.object_id = object_id(t.tablename)
                                    and c.name      = t.[column]
```

On the primary key, use `case` statement to check for the flag and append the keyword `primary key` after the column data type accordingly

```
CASE WHEN primarykey = 'yes' THEN ' primary key' ELSE '' END
```

incorporate into your query (untested)

```
query = 'CREATE TABLE ' + 
            QUOTENAME(table_name) +
            ' ( ' +
            STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(cl) + ' ' + data_type , 
              CASE WHEN primarykey = 'yes'
                   THEN ' primary key'
                   ELSE ''
                   END, ', ') +
            ' );'
```

Comment: this is giving error for string_agg function , syntax is incorrect please try to solve in your editor first sir

Comment: Please give it a go. It shouldn't be that hard to correct the syntax

Comment: syntax is correct , but sir it is not giving desired results.

Comment: show the query that you used and the result